# Maintaining object relational mapping with serialization

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, serialization, orm

I am trying to figure out a way to make some of my database objects serializable to and from XML files.

I am using an Entity Framework data model for my objects and making them available to my client using WCF RIA Services.  I want to be able to take a given object from the database and serialize it to an XML file, and vice-versa.

In the past I have tried this and the problems I run into are as follows:

- If I implement IXmlSerializable for each object, then at the time of deserialization each object knows nothing of the other objects being deserialized.  It is in a kind of bubble and it has no way of resolving a foreign key ID to an object reference.
- For the above problem, the only solution I found was to write one big serialization and deserialization method where a parent object keeps track of references and assign them as needed.  This feels like a very bad way of doing it since I have to constantly maintain this large method anytime an object changes, instead of each object being responsible for its own serialization.
- The standard XML design of nesting objects inside each other does not work well for ORM models.  The reason is that some objects may have references to and be used by multiple other objects, so I can't create those objects as sub-elements of a parent object.

Consider the following XML:

```
<User Name="John Smith">
    <FavoriteMovies>
        <Movie Name="The Big Lebowski" Year="1998" ... />
    </FavoriteMovies>
</User>

<User Name="Robert Jones">
   <FavoriteMovies>
       <Movie Name="The Big Lebowski" Year="1998" ... />
   </FavoriteMovies>
</User>
```

Clearly I shouldn't have two instances of the same movie.  Rather the serialization should look something like this:

```
<User Name="John Smith">
    <FavoriteMovies>
        <Id>5</Id>
    </FavoriteMovies>
</User>

<User Name="Robert Jones">
    <FavoriteMovies>
        <Id>5</Id>
    </FavoriteMovies>
</User>

<Movies>
    <Movie Id="5" Name="The Big Lebowski" Year="1998" ... />
</Movies>
```

WCF already knows how to serialize and deserialize my objects into SOAP/JSON/etc. using Data Services.  Is that something I can just re-use when serializing to an XML file?

It occurs to me that relying on a database foreign key ID probably won't work since in many cases the objects will have the default ID.  WCF manages to serialize the objects without relying on these being set, and the IDs are only assigned once it gets saved to the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with EF and how the object model works but for most objects that successfully are serialized/deserialized over WCF you can you just use the DataContractSerializer directly. Refer to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx) for a simple walkthrough.

Since you will not need the XML to be interoperable, you can probably also use the `preserveObjectReferences` setting to avoid redundant data.

Comment: Looks promising although it does seem to be extremely verbose and it serializes information about my EntityFramework model container.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend `Json.NET` serializer http://json.codeplex.com/ over DataContractSerializer as soon as the latter is being bit buggy. You can also look this question for example for more research about why `Json.Net` serializer is better.